# QED Lagrangian in terms of Weyl spinors

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, dirac-equation

Let's say the electron field can be written in term of its left and right handed Weyl spinors:
\begin{equation}
\psi_{e} = \begin{pmatrix} \chi \\ \eta^{\dagger} \end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation}

In which case  $\bar{\Psi_{e}}=(\eta \space \chi^{\dagger})$

The QED Lagrangian is: $\bar{\Psi_{e}}\gamma^{\mu}A_{\mu}\Psi_{e}$ which would yield the following two terms:

$\chi^{\dagger}\bar{\sigma^{\mu}}A_{\mu}\chi - \eta^{\dagger}\bar{\sigma^{\mu}}A_{\mu}\eta$

In reality there are 4 possible vertices. So, how does one reconcile the above two terms with the following four possible vertices:

$e_{L}e_{L}$,  $e_{R}e_{R}$,  $\bar{e_{L}}e_{R}$,  $e_{L}\bar{e_{R}}$

where $\bar{e}$ stands for positron.

Comment: Look at the gamma matrices in the chiral representation again and you'll see that you've made a mistake. Also what are you asking? Those are 4 possible mass terms but of course there are more possible vertices when other fields are involved

Comment: What I'm asking is in general you have two terms (written in chiral spinors) but in reality you can think of four possible vertices. So, how can one relate those two terms with the four possible interactions?

Comment: You must not forget why one needs the Dirac spinor and the Weyl one is not enough. Parity invariance of the theory. Pretty sure the 4 terms you wrote cannot be all acceptable as linear independent and parity invariant.

Comment: @physics_2015 1. Those are 4 *scalar* combinations. Vector field couples to the *vector* combination. So what are you trying to ask? 2. Your vector interactions are incorrect

Comment: @DanielC First two are Majorana mass terms that needs to be complemented by their Hermitian conjugates. Not good in QED unless you couple them to the charged scalar field. Other two are Hermitian conjugate parts of the Dirac mass. I think OP separates them because you can have two terms $\bar{\psi}\psi$ and $i\bar{\psi}\gamma_5\psi$. In QED you can turn those two into $\bar{\psi}\psi$ with no physical consequence. With electroweak interaction the phase will go to CKM.

Comment: @OON  , I'm not sure why you say the Lagrangian is wrong. Please look at equation (4.5.7) on page 56 of this paper:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.1594.pdf
How else do you want to write the QED Lagrangian in terms of Weyl spinors??

Comment: @OON when I wrote $e_{L}e_{L}$,... I was referring to a vertex containing two left handed electrons. In other words: $e_{L}\sigma^{\mu}A_{\mu}e_{L}$

Comment: @physics_2015 Now after the edit the formula is correct. The Pauli matrices has indices $\sigma^\mu_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}$ and $\bar{\sigma}^{\mu,\dot{\alpha}\alpha}$ with undotted indices being the spinor indices of the left Weyl spinors i.e. $\eta^\alpha$ and dotted indices - indices of the right Weyl spinors i.e. $\eta^\dagger_{\dot{\alpha}}$. Therefore if you have sigma at one side should be a left spinor and at another the right one. Therefore you can't have $e_L\sigma^\mu e_L$ but $e_L\sigma^\mu\bar{e}_L$ is a good object.

Comment: @physics_2015 On the other hand if you construct the scalar you contract the spinor indices directly $\eta\eta\equiv\eta^\alpha\eta_\alpha$ so $e_L e_L$ is a Lorentz scalar